# Best Approach for Managing CSS Stylesheets and Style Classes in a JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

I'm working on a JavaFX application with numerous CSS files. These CSS files are unique in that they don't extend control classes like `.vbox {}` or `.button {}`; instead, they define custom node CSS properties using IDs (e.g., `#custom-node-name {}`).

I'm currently faced with two possible approaches for integrating these CSS files into my application, and I'm concerned about their performance implications.

**Option 1: Apply All CSS Files Globally**

In this approach, I would add all of these CSS files to the scene or the scene's root `Parent` and reference the custom node properties through style classes that match the node's type. For example, if it's a button, I'd use `#custom-button`, and for a text field, `#custom-text-field`.

The potential issue here is that every node in my scene graph would have to search through every CSS stylesheet to find the style class it requires, which could be problematic in terms of performance.

**Option 2: Apply CSS Files to Individual Nodes**

In this alternative, I'd add the stylesheet to each individual node that needs access to the custom CSS property and then apply the corresponding style class to it. Similarly, if my `Pane` node contains multiple child nodes that require the same style class, I'd add the CSS file to the `Pane`, and all child nodes within it can access the style class.

The issue with this approach is that I might end up adding the same CSS stylesheet multiple times to the scene graph. For instance, different parts of the application might require the same styling for different nodes, resulting in redundant stylesheet references.

**My Question:**
Which approach is the most performant way of handling CSS stylesheets and style classes in a JavaFX application? Should I go with Option 1, Option 2, or is there a better approach that balances performance and maintainability?

Comment: I don't have data, but I find option 1 is significantly simpler to develop and maintain. Unless you've profiled a performance issue, and you've confirmed a more complicated solution provides measured improvements, I say use the simpler solution.

Comment: My advice is to use the design that best fits function and ease of development and maintenance rather than performance.  If performance was an absolute concern you might not use CSS at all, but that would be extreme and I wouldn’t recommend it.  The standard JavaFX controls have a single style sheet (modena.css in the JavaFX controls jar), so if you use any control then you will be using a massive style sheet (like your option 1) anyway.  I’m not sure why you would choose to style excursively via ids rather than classes, that seems a bit weird, but I guess if it works for you, then fine.

Comment: @jewelsea that makes sense, I use a custom colors stylesheet globally and then all nodes within scene have access to it. About styling classes, according to openJDK it really messes up with performance (you wouldn't notice it for small-medium size applications, but it changes when you have dozens of thousands of nodes rendering in scene graph as my application do).
https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Performance+Tips+and+Tricks

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

The best approach is to apply the CSS files globally for globally things, like button styling, etc.

If you have scene specific CSS, e.g. there is one button on a specific scene, which needs height 500px, then put this into a separate CSS file and add it to the scene.

Reasons for that:

1. Most easiest way to develop.
2. You know where you have your CSS.
3. Easier to maintain if you need to alter the color of your buttons e.g.
4. This is the way how it is done in web development too.
5. Your general scene CSS file contains only CSS you need on all scenes. This makes it very readable.
6. You don't have to bother with hundreds of specific CSS rules because exactly this rules are in a scene specific CSS file.
7. If you are having performance problems with this way to do it, then this way to do it is not the problem.

Rules of thumb:

1. Add CSS files only to root nodes or scenes directly.
2. Have a global/general CSS file which contains all general node styling.
3. Put node specific CSS into a separate Scene specific CSS file and add it to the scene.